# child.stdin.write loop causing app to crash

Tags: node.js, stdin, child-process

I am working on a app using nodeJS and have been trying to spawn a child process and sending input to the process.

However, sometimes I am having issues with nodemon telling me "[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..."

I believe looping thru an index and sending inputs to the program actually causes it to crash. So far i couldn't pinpoint what is wrong. Any advice or workaround would be greatly appreciated.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;;
child = spawn('java',['-classpath','ExampleFolder',filename]);

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length;i++){
sleep(1000); 
console.log(inputs[i]);
child.stdin.write(inputs[i]+"\n");
sleep(1000); 
}
```